# Knight's tour using Graph(DFS) Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, knights-tour

I'm trying to implement knight's tour using DFS. My board is 5x5 for simplicity.

below is my code

```
class StackK
   {
   private final int SIZE = 25;
   private int[] st;
   private int top;
// ------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean isFull()
   {return (top == SIZE-1);}
// ------------------------------------------------------------
   public StackK()           // constructor
      {
  st = new int[SIZE];    // make array
  top = -1;
  }
  public void push(int j)   // put item on stack
      { st[++top] = j; }
// ------------------------------------------------------------
   public int pop()          // take item off stack
  { return st[top--]; }
// ------------------------------------------------------------
   public int peek()         // peek at top of stack
  { return st[top]; }
// ------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean isEmpty()  // true if nothing on st   ack
      { return (top == -1); }
// ------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class StackK
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class VertexK
   {
   public String label;        // label (e.g. 'A')
   public boolean wasVisited;
   public int lastVisited;
// ------------------------------------------------------------
   public VertexK()   // constructor
      {
      label = "O";
      wasVisited = false;
      lastVisited = 0;
      }
// ------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class VertexK
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class GraphK
   {
   private final int SIZE = 5;
   private final int AREA = 5*5;
   private VertexK vertexList[]; // list of vertices
   private int adjMat[][];      // adjacency matrix
   private int nVerts;          // current number of vertices
   private StackK theStack;


// ------------------------------------------------------------
   public GraphK()               // constructor
      {
      vertexList = new VertexK[AREA];// chess board


  adjMat = new int[AREA][AREA];// adjacency matrix


  nVerts = 0; // number of vertices

  for(int y=0; y<SIZE; y++)      // set adjacency
     for(int x=0; x<SIZE; x++)   //    matrix to 0
        adjMat[x][y] = 0;

  theStack = new StackK(); //initialize stack


  for(int i=0;i<AREA;i++)  // make a chess board
       addVertex();


  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) // add all possible moves to adjMat
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            addMoves(i, j);
  }
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
   public void displayBoard(){
   int count =0;
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
           System.out.print(vertexList[(count+j)].label+" ");
       }
       count = count+5;
       System.out.println("");
   }
   System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
   }
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
   public void addMoves(int i, int j)
    {
    int currentRow = i*SIZE; //row
    int currentCol = j; //col
    int currentVertex = currentRow+currentCol;

    if(i-1>=0){
        if(j-2>=0){
            addEdge(currentVertex,currentVertex-SIZE-2);
        }
        if(j+2<SIZE){
            addEdge(currentVertex,currentVertex-SIZE+2);
        }
    }
    if(i+1<SIZE)
    {
        if(j-2>=0){
            addEdge(currentVertex, currentVertex+SIZE-2);
        }
        if(j+2<SIZE){
            addEdge(currentVertex, currentVertex+SIZE+2);
        }
    }
    if(i-2>=0){
        if(j-1>=0){
            addEdge(currentVertex, currentVertex-(SIZE*2)-1);
        }
        if(j+1<SIZE){
            addEdge(currentVertex,currentVertex-(SIZE*2)+1);
        }

    }
    if(i+2<SIZE){
        if(j-1>=0){
            addEdge(currentVertex,currentVertex+(SIZE*2)-1);
        }
        if(j+1<SIZE){
            addEdge(currentVertex,currentVertex+(SIZE*2)+1);
        }
    }


}


// ------------------------------------------------------------
   public void addVertex()
      {
      vertexList[nVerts++] = new VertexK();
      }
// ------------------------------------------------------------
   public void addEdge(int start, int end)
      {
      adjMat[start][end] = 1;
      }


// ------------------------------------------------------------
   public void dfs()  // depth-first search
   {                                 
   vertexList[0].wasVisited = true;  
   vertexList[0].label = "V";                
   theStack.push(0);


   while( !theStack.isEmpty() )      
  {
  if(theStack.isFull()){
      System.out.println("You Win");
  }
  int last = theStack.peek();
  int v = getNext( theStack.peek() );

  if(v == -1){

     System.out.println("DEAD END HERE");
     theStack.pop();
     vertexList[last].label = "O";
     displayBoard();

  }
  else                           
     {

     vertexList[v].label = "V";
     displayBoard();
     vertexList[v].lastVisited = last;
     vertexList[v].wasVisited = true;  

     theStack.push(v);                
     }
  }  // end while

   // stack is empty, so we're done
       }

  // ------------------------------------------------------------
 // returns an unvisited VertexK adj to v
 public int getNext(int v)
   {
   for(int j=0; j<nVerts; j++)
      if(adjMat[v][j]==1 && vertexList[j].wasVisited==false)
     return j;
   return -1;
   }  // end getAdjUnvisitedVertexK()
 // ------------------------------------------------------------
     public void displayAdj()
 {
    for(int i=0;i<AREA;i++){
    System.out.print(i+"th row: ");
    for(int k=0;k<AREA;k++)
        System.out.print(adjMat[i][k]);
    System.out.println("");
    }
 }
// ------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class GraphK

public class KnightApp
   {
   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  GraphK k = new GraphK();

  k.displayAdj();
  k.dfs();
  k.displayBoard();


  }  // end main()
   }  // end class DFSApp
```

My program starts out at index 0 and goes to index 7 as you would notice if you ran the code, this is not the right solution(I also wrote knight's tour recursively to check where I should start to get the right solution). So it's supposed to backtrack all the way to the starting square which is 0,0 and go to index 11 instead it just stops because the while loop is over when theStack is empty. How can I make it still go when it backtracks all the way back to the starting point also how do I mark the visited squares to false again when backtracking. LIFT TJE BAN

thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are not required to implement the stack yourself, you might want to look into [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html). Do you hold the possible moves for each field on the board? Propably you need to remove the field you came from (while backtracking) and try the next in the list. Btw reducing the posted code to the real problematic  part does not only help you debugging it but also increases the chances to get a useful answer.

Comment: implmenting the stack is really not necessary, but the other parts are essential to the whole I think, that's why I included the entire code. I'm having trouble backtracking.

Comment: You don't need an explicit stack. Instead you can just use recursion, which makes the solution *much* more readable

Comment: one possible algorithm with you stack aproach would be: field 0 - look what possible destination fields you have - save them for field 0 - go to the first on the list - if you have no destination fiels on field 1 - go back to field 0, remove field 1 from the list of possible destinations - go to the next field on the list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find a dead end, you need to make wasVisted of current Vertex to false, remove it from adjacency of its (current's) last vertex and set its(current's) lastVistied to zero:
So now the if condition in method dfs will be:

```
if (v == -1) {
    System.out.println("DEAD END HERE");
    theStack.pop();
    vertexList[last].label = "O";
    vertexList[last].wasVisited = false;
    adjMat[vertexList[last].lastVisited][last] = 0;
    vertexList[last].lastVisited = 0;
    displayBoard();
}
```

Comment: please let me know it worked or not? On my end it went to 11 from 0 after backtracking from 7